# jenkins always passes though test in rails fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, testunit

I am running jenkins with ubuntu 10.04 slave. In slave, I have configured rails 2.3.14 and metrical in the slave. Though one of the test cases fails, Jenkins reports that build has passed.

Please help and I  have no clue as to what is happening.

Comment: What does your jenkins config look like?

Comment: I am using ssh to slave and executing shell command like 'rake db:migrate && metrical'. Do I have to set the environment variables? Currently I am setting environment variable other than java home.

Comment: Do you have found a solution for this? Jenkins don't detect failing tests at my server

Answer (score 0):

Since the actual build is happening out of jenkins slave, we are expected to have JVM options, PATH set for the jenkins slave.

My Jenkins slave's JVM options is set as 
 `-Xmx1300m -Xms500M  -XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xss8m`

This solves the problem.